# gradle Build Error: Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'

Tags: android, debugging, gradle, build

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
```

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app

What is this error after Gradle Build?

Comment: post your entire gradle file

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines in gradle to solve the problem:- Below lines forces to use the annotations library version to 26.1.0.

```
android{    
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
        }
    }
```

And do not forget to add following code, if you want to run the AndroidTest

```
 defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force the annotation library in your test using:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
```

Something like this:

```
// Force usage of support annotations in the test app, since it is internally used by the runner module.

  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.1'
```

Another solution is to use this in the top level file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
}
```